# Getting Data from automatically generates WTForms from MongoEngine models

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-mongoengine

How do I get the data from a WTForms form after submitting it?

Models:

```
class User(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField(required=True)
UserForm = model_form(User)
```

Views:

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def add_user():
    form = UserForm()
    if form.form.validate_on_submit():
        print(form.name.data)
return render_template('user.html', form=form)
```

And here's the form HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name(size=20) }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: currently what is happening? are you getting any errors? Is the value getting printed for `print(form.name.data)`?

Comment: This print None

Comment: I dont think its entering the `if`. it should be `form.validate_on_submit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Form Validation with WTForms](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/wtforms/)

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def add_user():
    form = UserForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        print(form.name.data)
return render_template('user.html', form=form)
```